# Increase integer when a child is added or changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord in rails and I have a model named Menu, many other models belong to Menu: Ingredient, Product, ProductSize, Category, ...

And to those models other models belong to: ProductPrice belongs to Product, ...

I have an attribute named version:integer in Menu.  what would the cleanest approach be to increase this integer every time model that belongs_to that menu is inserted/deleted/edited?  I could probably solve this with an after_save callback in the child models but I'm not sure it that would be the best approach.

Edit: using Parandroid tip I came up with this:

```
class MenuObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :ingredient, :product, :menu_category, :ingredient_category, :product_type, :product_size, :product_price

  def after_save(model)
    model.menu.version = model.menu.version + 1;
    model.menu.save!
  end
end
```

Which works perfectly.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the after_save approach. I would love to be proved wrong, though.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear, I want the version of Menu to increase when a Product or Category or Ingredients or ...  is altered that belongs_to that menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think observers can help you. See [that link!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).

Answer (score 0):

An `after_save` callback would probably your cleanest approach. You could also perform method overwriting.

```
def update_attributes
    self.version += 1
    super
end
```

but I believe an `after_save` is way better